# Why is the download of images blocked when viewing it after Google image search, but not when "open image in new tab"?

Tags: google-chrome, images

I've recently searched some images via Google image search:

1. Search for "oscar the grouch pinterest"
2. Click on the first image
3. Click on "View image" (or similar, I use the German version)
4. Now the URL should be https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/3f/c6/03/3fc60371e23e9be6bebce7c392b27bcc.jpg
5. Right-click on the image: "Save image as... " or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>
6. It looks as if it was downloaded, but below the name it denotes "Failed - Blocked"
7. Right-click on the image, "Open image in new tab"
8. Right-click on the image: "Save image as... " or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>

Why does 5 work but not 8? Both have the same url...